# Traverse the graph to get possible topology

Tags: neo4j

I am writing my master thesis with Neo4j Database and I meet a problem. I need your help.
[image]

The picture at left is the data I saved in Neo4j, the whole picture represents how an application could be deployed in cloud. Every node represents a service.
For example, I have an Apach Module and I can "hosted_on" an Apache Server. The green line represents a possible option, because an Apache server can hosted on a Windows system or a Linux system.

So there are two possibilities for deployment, showed at right.

At right is what I want, I call it topology, it defines how an application deployment looks like.

what I want is to retrieve all possible typologies.

How I can get these possibilities topology by Cypher or Java traverse API?

Thanks very much..

Comment: What is the "possible topology which caused by relationship alt_hosted_on"? Can you describe what kind of result you want and what you have tried so far?

Comment: This sounds interesting, but I agree you need to define what a "topology" is in this context.  Are you referring to a formal math concept, or something else?

Comment: Hi, dear Martin and FrobberOfBits, I have updated my question to make it clear, would you provide your advice? thank  you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are getting at, but it might be helpful to consider the "What is related and how?" query:

```
// What is related, and how
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
WHERE labels(a) <> [] AND labels(b) <> []
RETURN DISTINCT head(labels(a)) AS This, type(r) as To, head(labels(b)) AS That
LIMIT 10
```

This will return Node labels and relationship names that are connected by at least one relationship in the graph. Is that what you mean by topology?

Comment: Hi William, Sorry I did not make the question clear, I have updated the question, Would you take a look at it again?  thanks